# In pgAdmin3 how can I get a UI similar to MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, pgadmin

I am very new to PostgreSQL and use pgAdmin3 with a PostgreSQL Database.

I am not so good with writing SQL queries. In MySQL Workbench there is a EER UI (diagram representation) that helps us draw new tables easily. Is there a similar graphical representation of EER diagrams in PostgreSQL? If yes, how can I use it to draw a new table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pgAdmin III has no point-and-click interface to build a query.

There is, however, a dialog that helps you create tables.

Comment: it will be difficult for beginners who dont know queries rite. :(

Comment: It is even more difficult for beginners if they click around, something happens that they do not want and they do not know why. In other words: learning a little SQL will improve your professional life tremendously.

Comment: Am good with my MySql workbench and query usage , I cant spend time in developing query and execute them. If there is UI tool like in Mysql Workbench it will help us to complete task soon.